# Visual Studio crashes on 'add reference'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio crashes when opening any solution and right-clicking 'references' and choosing 'add reference'. The dialog opens for a few seconds, VS crashes and restarts. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS2013, then uninstalling again with VS Uninstaller and reinstalling, and installing VS2015. Problem persists on both new installations. Had Beckhoff TwinCAT 3.1 installed but uninstalled also this before first reinstalling Visual Studio, to no avail.

Is there a registry key or specific locations where all VS installations look for packages?

Comment: Try [VS Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases)

Comment: That's what I used to uninstall, I actually reinstalled VS once in between. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Try [Diagnostic Mode](http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/) then. Hopefully it's just errant file and not requiring Windows reinstall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by doing another reinstall of Visual Studio, but this time cleaning remnants manually. VS Uninstaller **DOES NOT** do a complete uninstall.

Answer (score -1):

> **WARNING: This will reset all project settings in your
>   solution!**

I had the same problem. Just delete `.vs\<solution name>` folder and reopen the solution and add the reference.